# How can I build a responsive navbar using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I build a navbar for my website in Flutter as in the code below. All I want to do is to make this navbar responsive for mobile version. I want that in mobile version to show a menu icon and the text of my pages should disappear and I can see it when I click this menu icon. Does anyone knows how can I do this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF262533),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(  
                  height: Get.height * .65, width: Get.width,       
                  color:  const Color(0xFF262533),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 80,
                        width: 185,
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo2.png'),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      const Text(
                        "Escorts",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Angenturen & Clubs",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Inserieren",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Werben",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Blog",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                      const Text(
                        "Kontakt",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                        ),
                      ),
                      const Spacer(),
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.attach_money,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.chat,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.person,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 20,
                      ),
                      const Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        width: 32,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```

[image: e]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### - update

i just wrote an article about responsive layout. We ca use `Padding`,  `LayoutBuilder` (like my answer below), and my best choice is with `extension context`.

here you can read it:

##### https://medium.easyread.co/3-options-for-creating-responsive-layouts-in-flutter-app-live-demo-68b0c0e955ab

---

you use `LayoutBuilder()` and create condition you need:

eg:

```
LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
  if (constraints.maxWidth >= 1500) {
    return desktopNavbar;
  } else if (constraints.maxWidth >= 650) {
    return tabletNavbar;
  } else {
    return mobileNavbar;
  }
});
```

create another component for each layout:

```
Widget mobileNavbar(){
 return Row(
  children: [ specific widget you want to show on mobile ]
 )
}
```

and so on for desktop or tablet.

Comment: Please can you use my code to explain me this? I'm really confused. @pmatatias

Comment: update your code, where did you put that Container? , i cant give specific example only from that code

Comment: You can find my updated code now @pmatatias

Comment: I'm waiting your response @pmatatias

Answer (score 0):

You should use Media Query to give height and width as it will set these properties according to the device size. You should be doing it like this.

like:

```
Container(
 height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.65,
 width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.65,
  ),
```

Comment: No it didn't worked @Nil Dervalia

Answer (score 0):

try this use size class config

```
class SizeConfig {
  SizeConfig._();
  static final SizeConfig _instance = SizeConfig._();
  factory SizeConfig() => _instance;

  late MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  late double screenWidth;
  late double screenHeight;
  late double blockSizeHorizontal;
  late double blockSizeVertical;
  late double _safeAreaHorizontal;
  late double _safeAreaVertical;
  late double safeBlockHorizontal;
  late double safeBlockVertical;
  double? profileDrawerWidth;
  late double refHeight;
  late double refWidth;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    refHeight = 1450;
    refWidth = 670;

    if (screenHeight < 1200) {
      blockSizeHorizontal = screenWidth / 100;
      blockSizeVertical = screenHeight / 100;

      _safeAreaHorizontal =
          _mediaQueryData.padding.left + _mediaQueryData.padding.right;
      _safeAreaVertical =
          _mediaQueryData.padding.top + _mediaQueryData.padding.bottom;
      safeBlockHorizontal = (screenWidth - _safeAreaHorizontal) / 100;
      safeBlockVertical = (screenHeight - _safeAreaVertical) / 100;
    } else {
      blockSizeHorizontal = screenWidth / 120;
      blockSizeVertical = screenHeight / 120;

      _safeAreaHorizontal =
          _mediaQueryData.padding.left + _mediaQueryData.padding.right;
      _safeAreaVertical =
          _mediaQueryData.padding.top + _mediaQueryData.padding.bottom;
      safeBlockHorizontal = (screenWidth - _safeAreaHorizontal) / 120;
      safeBlockVertical = (screenHeight - _safeAreaVertical) / 120;
    }
  }

  double getWidthRatio(double val) {
    double res = (val / refWidth) * 100;
    double temp = res * blockSizeHorizontal;

    return temp;
  }

  double getHeightRatio(double val) {
    double res = (val / refHeight) * 100;
    double temp = res * blockSizeVertical;
    return temp;
  }

  double getFontRatio(double val) {
    double res = (val / refWidth) * 100;
    double temp = 0.0;
    if (screenWidth < screenHeight) {
      temp = res * safeBlockHorizontal;
    } else {
      temp = res * safeBlockVertical;
    }

    return temp;
  }
}

extension SizeUtils on num {
  double get toWidth => SizeConfig().getWidthRatio(toDouble());
  double get toHeight => SizeConfig().getHeightRatio(toDouble());
  double get toFont => SizeConfig().getFontRatio(toDouble());
}
```

Comment: Where can I use it at my code please? @Nil

Comment: SizedBox(
                        height: Get.height * .6,
                        width: Get.width * .18,
                        child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                      ),  

use getX or direct class object use
or 
  final screenhight = SizeConfig().blockSizeVertical; then use

Comment: I don't get it @Nil

Comment: Please use my code and tell me how to use it there @Nil

Comment: CHECK THIS EXAMPLE 
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-effectively-scale-ui-according-to-different-screen-sizes-2cb7c115ea0a

CHANGE AS PER REQUIREMENT

Comment: Look I'm building a website but now i have to make my navbar responsive for mobile. That's all. I don't think this solution can solve my problem @Nil

Comment: SHARE SCREEN SHOTS

Comment: I updated my question, You can see the screenshot there @Nil

Answer (score 0):

To hide certain widgets based on screen you can just only include them when the screen is big enough. For example, simply replace

```
const Text(
  "Escorts",
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins'
  )
)
```

with

```
if (Get.width > 1000) const Text(
  "Escorts",
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: 'Poppins'
  )
)
```

Similarly you can only show the menu icon when the width is small enough

Comment: It says undefined name "Get" @Ivo

Comment: @Amarildo your code already shows `Get.width` at another place so it should work. Otherwise use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`